# Cutting HTML in bash

Tags: html, bash, parsing, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I am currently trying to cut a HTML file to a certain phrase, or between two phrases.

```
<p>unneeded text and top of webpage</p>
    <h2><span style="font-size&#58;18px;">text1</span></h2><pre><b>text2&#58;</b>
admin (you)
    password&#58; password1
adminline2
    password&#58; password2
adminline3
    password&#58; password3
adminline4
    password&#58; password4

<b>Authorized Users&#58;</b>
userline
userline2
userline3
</pre><h2><span style="font-size&#58;18px;">text3</span</h2><ul><li>
more unneeded text and bottem of the web page</ul></li>
```

Using the Bash Terminal, I am trying to cut out the top and the bottom of the html of this webpage, to get:

```
<h2><span style="font-size&#58;18px;">text1</span></h2><pre><b>text2&#58;</b>
    admin (you)
        password&#58; password1
    adminline2
        password&#58; password2
    adminline3
        password&#58; password3
    adminline4
        password&#58; password4

    <b>Authorized Users&#58;</b>
    userline
    userline2
    userline3
    </pre><h2><span style="font-size&#58;18px;">text3</span</h2>
```

I tried using cut, but you can only have a one character delim. I also tried using awk to cut down the top like this:

```
STARTHTML='<h2><span style="font-size&#58;18px;">text1</span></h2><pre><b>text2&#58;</b>'
awk 'BEGIN {FS="$STARTHTML";}{print $2}' ~/Desktop/input.txt
```

But the output ends up being a bunch of blank lines.

How can I cut down this .txt or .html file of a webpage, down to these specific lines using just bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your desired output,Can you check if this works:

```
sed -n '/<h2>/,/<\/pre>/p' file_name
```

Explanation:

As you need the lines between the patterns starting with `<h2>--start pattern` and `</pre> --End pattern`, i included those inside  the `sed` syntax

```
sed -n '/start_pattern_here/,/end_pattern_here/p' file_name


-n     : Suppress automatic printing of pattern space
p      : Print the current pattern space
```

Comment: This worked and cut down to the exact lines i need, could you explain more how this works? I am new to bash.